# i'm creating a car class where you can create your own car but it does not work

Tags: python

"trying to create a program where you can create your own car . problem is that i get an error message i don't understand. the program itself you should be able to create a car and put in the year model. i might be over my head here since i have never used class function before"

```
"error messages"
" line 1, in <module> class Car:"
" line 13, in Car print("i have now goten my  ",a.getYear(),"year model")"
"NameError: name 'a' is not defined"
```

Code:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.Year= a

    def getYear(self):
        return self.Year

    def setYear(self, a):
        self.year = a
        return

    print("i have now goten my  ",a.getYear(),"year model")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes...try this code..it should work:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self):
        a = 0
        self.Year= a

    def getYear(self):
        return self.Year

    def setYear(self, a):
        self.Year = a
        print("i have now goten my  ", self.getYear(),"year model")
        #return self.Year

bmw = Car()
bmw.setYear(10)
```

This should give you:

```
i have now goten my   10 year model
```

Answer (score 0):

a is a variable right ?
Then you are using it inside a function, wich will not work if you don't put a `global`.
How does it work ?
Exemple :

```py
a = "hello"
def print():
    print(a)
print()
```

The output should be "hello", right ? But the function is like a second script inside your first one, so you need to tell him to go and search for the vraiable out of the function. So :

```py
a = "hello"
def print():
    global a
    print(a)
print()
```

And the output is "hello", because now a is a global varibale wich will work for both main script and function !

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, a=11):
        self.Year = a

    def getYear(self):
        return self.Year

    def setYear(self, a=22):
        self.Year = a
        print("I have now goten my", self.getYear(), "year model")


car1 = Car()


# def __init__
car1.Year  # default Year
print("This is default year {}".format(car1.Year))
car1.Year = 4  # e.g 4 year
print("This is e.g year {}".format(car1.Year))

# getYear(self):
print("This is get year {}".format(car1.getYear()))

# def setYear
car1.setYear()
car1.setYear(5)
```

This will gives You:

```
    This is default year 11
    This is e.g year 4
    This is get year 4
    I have now goten my 22 year model
    I have now goten my 5 year model
```